# Compile and Run Coffeescript in Sublime Text 2

Tags: coffeescript, sublimetext, sublimetext2

Has anone had any luck both compiling and running CoffeeScript files in Sublime Text 2 with the TextMate bundle https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script-tmbundle

**CoffeeScript.sublime-build**

```
{
"path": "/usr/local/bin",
"cmd": ["coffee","$file"],
"file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.coffee"
}
```

Anyway to enable both the compile **and** compile selected text commands in Sublime Text 2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Multiple builds were added in 2197 
http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=7180

Comment: This is phenomenal. I went to great lengths to sort-of implement this using plugins but I am glad to hear that it will be supported natively.

Answer (score 2):

If by "multiple build commands" you mean to pass different compile options to CoffeeScript you can check out this blog post to see how I did it:

http://hectorcorrea.com/Blog/Compiling-CoffeeScript-from-Sublime-Text-2

Basically I implemented on using the same approach that you did (via the Build menu) and the remaining I had to implement with plugins.

The answer by @atomi indicates that this will be supported natively soon which would be very nice.

Answer (score 1):

The setup here looks pretty promising.  Evidently you can bind a key combo to a command, in this case just running coffee on the file.

http://soenkerohde.com/2011/11/coffeescript-with-sublime-text/

Answer (score 0):

I found that using Node on OSX I needed a variation on [@Hector's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10730053/1450420).

I created a new `CoffeeScriptRun.sublime-build` file (Tools > Build System > New Build System) which looked like this:

```
{
  "cmd": ["coffee", "$file"],
  "selector" : "source.coffee",
  "path" : "/Users/derekhill/.nvm/v0.10.35/bin"
}
```

That path is the directory from `which node` (i.e. without the "node" at the end)

Then [Wes Bos's blog post](http://wesbos.com/sublime-text-build-scripts/) had a helpful explanation of what each part means:

- `cmd` is an array of commands that will be run.
- `selector` is an optional way to scope the build script to a specific filetype
- `path` is where the command is to be executed. Because Sublime executes it in the python console, we need to specify where on our system the compiler we want to use lies.

So basically this is equivalent to going to the node directory and running `coffee my_file.coffee`